# PHP: "Trying to get property of non-object" with json file

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get values from a JSON file in the same directory, but keep getting a "Trying to get property of non-object" notice. I'm very inexperienced with JSON, and can't spot any differences between my files and the references I'm using. I've done a bit of research looking at similar problems on here, mainly looking at the using {} and [], but nothing I've tried has works. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
$myJSON = file_get_contents("myfile.json");

$phpVersion = json_decode($myJSON);

$name = $phpVersion->name;
$birthdate = $phpVersion->birthdate;
$city = $phpVersion->address->city;
$state = $phpVersion->address->state;
?>
```

and myfile.json is:

```
{
    "name": "First Last",
    "phone_number": "123-456-7890",
"birthdate": "01-01-1985",
"address":
    [
        "street": "123 Main St",
        "city": "Pleasantville",
        "state": "California",
        "zip": "99999",
    ]
"time_of_death": ""
}
```

I'm a little unsure if that's the correct format for address, but I'm very certain it's not what is causing the issue. I am getting the notice for all four lines of the php file. Thanks!

EDIT: Got it working. It ended up being a cross between Sahil and FrenchMajesty's suggestions. The comma had to be moved and the brackets had to be changed to braces. Thanks everyone!

Comment: What does `var_dump($phpVersion)` display?

Comment: Remove the comma after zip and place it after ]. That's why your JSON object is corrupted

Comment: var_dump shows NULL.

Comment: Still getting the same errors after moving the comma.

Answer (score 0):

Your `JSON` is **`not valid`** if you try to `json_decode`, Hopefully you will get this error.

> **Error:** array value separator ',' expected

```
{
    "name": "First Last",
    "phone_number": "123-456-7890",
"birthdate": "01-01-1985",
"address":
    [ //<---- issue is here
        "street": "123 Main St",
        "city": "Pleasantville",
        "state": "California",
        "zip": "99999",//<---- issue is here
    ] //<---- issue is here
"time_of_death": ""
}
```

A **`valid json`** can be this

```
{
    "name": "First Last",
    "phone_number": "123-456-7890",
    "birthdate": "01-01-1985",
    "address": {
        "street": "123 Main St",
        "city": "Pleasantville",
        "state": "California",
        "zip": "99999"
    },
    "time_of_death": ""
}
```

**PHP code:** [**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/784923)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$json='{
    "name": "First Last",
    "phone_number": "123-456-7890",
    "birthdate": "01-01-1985",
    "address": {
        "street": "123 Main St",
        "city": "Pleasantville",
        "state": "California",
        "zip": "99999"
    },
    "time_of_death": ""
}';
$phpVersion=json_decode($json);

echo $name = $phpVersion->name;
echo $birthdate = $phpVersion->birthdate;
echo $city = $phpVersion->address->city;
echo $state = $phpVersion->address->state;
```

Comment: After making these changes I'm still getting the same notices, and var_dump($phpVersion) is still showing NULL. So it still doesn't like my JSON file.

Comment: Don't worry about it. I got it working. Will update the main post.